# Intuition why $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times H) \neq 0$ cannot be satisfied

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

I found very understandable proofs why $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times H) = 0$ might be zero. But I do not derive any understanding out of it.

Imagine I have any source field. Why cannot I use Stokes Theorem on it and construct a field which would have the source field as curl?

Comment: The divergence measures accumulation or dispersion at the point while the curl measures how much it rotates. Spinning something like a coin or a top doesn't make it accumulate or disperse so it must have no divergence.

Comment: Just in case I have not mentioned it: All of this was discovered by Paul Dirac when he was thinking about the existence of magnetic monopoles.